# How to use MATLAB to automatically remove unwant object in an image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have already done some image segmentation in MATLAB. The attached picture is the result. My question is that how I can automatically remove the tree part (bottom part) from the image? In other words, I need to isolate the bird with the surrounding. I need to write up a method to do that because I have hundreds of those images.  Thanks

[image: The image]

Comment: That sounds like a general color image segmentation problem - which is not trivial at all. Many things depend on what kind of solution would be useful for your images. Perhaps you should go for a pixel-classification techniques and train a classifier with sets of pixels from different classes (non-bird, bird). You could try doing the classification in RGB-space first.

Comment: Its important that the question you ask shows some research effort also. So please also tell about what you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

If this answer looks good enough to you then download the following code: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32532 and try the following commands:

```
I = rgb2gray(imread('BO1NO.jpg'));
th = 0.35 * max(max(I));
[P, J] = regionGrowing(I, [240,390], th, 300, 'true', 'true', 'false');
figure;imshow(J)
```

Since you can see clear intensity difference between the bird and the wooded branch, its much more logical to try something like region growing approach than anything else. If I were you, the next thing I would try is some color image segmentation algorithm. Since I get a feel than when we convert from RGB-> Gray, we loose some useful information. Bcoz in gray version of the image, wooden branch has a somewhat same values as the bird (in few regions). So better work on the color image directly without converting to gray. Do NOT rush towards using any pattern classifier. It may solve your problem but it ain't smart thing to do if there are easier/cheaper solutions available. There are more than one ways to solve this problem strictly within the boundaries of Image Processing without intruding into Pattern Recognition/Machine Learning.

Comment: Nice :) Yes, region growing is much better than global segmentation.  It would be interesting to hear from OP if it worked on all his images? Because you still need to define the seed-pixel. Why 0.35? Is this tuned to this exact image?

Comment: @OleThomsenBuus - I had only one image so I had to tune it on that :( I would be glad to test it on a set of images.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this code and see if it is what you need:

```
I = imread('BO1NO.jpg');

% level = graythresh(I); BW = im2bw(I, level);figure;imshow(BW)

BW = im2bw(rgb2gray(I), 0.25);figure;imshow(BW);
```

% Remove largest connected component (i.e. bird) in the BW image and this gives the branch predominantly. So subtract the resultant image from the original BW image. The difference image is bird.

```
BW1 = BW;
CC = bwconncomp(BW);


numPixels = cellfun(@numel,CC.PixelIdxList);

[biggest,idx] = max(numPixels);

BW(CC.PixelIdxList{idx}) = 0;

figure, imshow(BW);

figure, imshow(BW1);

Ir = imsubtract(BW1,BW);

figure;imshow(Ir)
```

Check thresholding using otsu's method for threshold selection also.

Comment: You should indent the code so that it appears in the correct way (indent with 4 spaces). You shold also comment the code and explain a bit what it is doing. How come you believe that global tresholding is going to solve this general image analysis problem?

Comment: 2. What makes you think global thresholding cannot solve this problem? Totally depends on how much accuracy you are expecting. I can see clear intensity difference in the bird and the branch. SO I won't recommend any pattern classifier approach in the very first place. What I would recommend is: Try a global thresholding approach with some pre/post processing and see if it works. If not, then try color image segmentation. And, if that also does not work THEN ONLY go for a pattern classifier as its usually more work and more complex system that the other two.

Comment: Don't underestimate the power of global thresholding :) A little bit of pre/post processing can really give nice results :)

Comment: Okay - Occam's Razor - I get your point. But I just have bad experience with global tresholding. It was usually my first techqique some years ago, and it never really gave good results. It is just too general an assumption that images can be segmented using a global cutoff og color/intensity. That is atleast my experience. But perhaps it works here. For me any image analysis problem should always be seen as a statistical pattern classification problem. It is the strongest of all preliminary approaches.

Comment: @OleThomsenBuus - I agree with you that in most of the cases global thresholding may not work but if it works, usually thats bcoz of the added pre/post processing. In those cases it saves you a LOT of computation compared to any other algorithms. Thats why i still try it first for few mins :)